# MySql error #1005 - Can't create table

Tags: php, mysql, yii, phpmyadmin

I write a query when doing a tutorial Agile web application development with yii. I was trying to alter a table with this query and got this error in phpmyadin

```
#1005 - Can't create table 'trackstar_dev.#sql-152_16' (errno: 121) (<a href="server_engines.php?engine=InnoDB&amp;page=Status&amp;token=af80b3320dff7dfda18d88d97fe80da4">Details...</a>)
```

Here is my query

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_project_user_assignment` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_project_
user` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_project` (`id`) ON
DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
```

Can Anyone help please ?

Comment: What permissions does your user account have?

Comment: He means the permissions for the user running the query. Also may be a stupid question; but does the table `tbl_project` exist too?

Comment: yes. tbl_project exists . And I,m running this query in my localhost so it would be root user.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when table `tbl_project_user_assignment` has already records which `project_id` is not found on the table (*which you want to reference*) `tbl_project`.`id`. The best way you can do is to empty the `tbl_project_user_assignment` and alter it again to add the constraint.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But table is already empty. I also does it again after seeing your answer. But still same issue . Any help ? :(